# Clear Blender materials slots

Tags: materials

I have a scene where a large number of redundant cycles materials have accumulated. I'd like to have them removed so that there's nothing left remaining in the materials slots at all.
[image]

I've tried all the methods I could find of deleting them so that they don't show up in the slots like this but none have worked so far.

That is selecting all objects w an active object as well and 'copy material to others', saving, closing re-opening, no luck. And the Ctrl L method as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5454/599

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the follow script

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Materials_Utils

I hope that script be of help for you

Comment: I enabled the script, but how do I use it? What hotkey do I use to start it? I'm using Cycles.