# Find users of a material / texture / image which is not displayed in the outliner

Tags: workflow, edit-mode, shaders

How can one search by name for a material / texture / image datablock that is not displayed in the outliner, for example because it's buried somewhere deep inside a node tree?

Let me please describe some typical use cases to make more clear what I'm talking about:

- When a material / texture / image datablock is 'buried' in the node
  tree, not displayed in the outliner, and you have a lot of materials
  with complex node trees, you often have a hard time finding one by
  name.
- For me, the most common use case is to find if seemingly-orphaned
  datablocks (mostly named xxx.001 etc.) are still in use somewhere:
  There are often some datablocks which stay orphaned in the blendfile
  because the user count has not been set to zero correctly, and the
  more complex the shaders, the more likely this is. You can
  shift-delete them, but you have to make 100% sure that they are not
  in use anywhere.
- Besides this, it is often necessary for complex materials, especially when you
  have been linking/appending and copy-pasting parts of the node tree
  from other files. If the appended part uses, for instance, a texture with a name that is also used in your destination blend file, you may have to check if the textures are identical, and therefore find the other one.

Once saw an addon which did similar stuff, but not exactly this. Don't remember which, unfortunately.

Any ideas how we can make our lives easier keeping our blend files clean?

Best greetings, Michael

Comment: You might be able to write a quick bit of python like in [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5465/599).

Comment: maybe this is the answer... but still I hope it's not... to my understanding, this means your script, in order not to be a workaround, but a safe and clean solution, would have to 'manually' iterate over every type of datablock that you can imagine as a user.  Is this right? Or is there any other possible, cleaner way maybe?

Comment: Yes, it's what that script does. I can't immediately think of any other way, but even on large files it shouldn't take that long (maybe a few seconds at most).

Answer (score 11):

You can set your outliner to `Blender File` mode. This will show even datablocks with no users. Under `materials` you will find a list of all materials in alphabetical order. You can even search for datablocks by name in the small search field at the top:
[image]

To find users of a datablock, perform the same search in `All Scenes` mode instead of Blender File mode.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm often using this setting. However, the users of the datablocks are not shown... that's what makes it difficult (and why I'm asking).

Comment: I've found the file now in "Blender File" mode. If I click "Unlink" I get: "Not yet implemented". How can I remove this file? (blender cycles 2.72)